# Facebook iOS SDK invite with multiline message

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to figure out how to send an invite using Facebook SDK for iOS, but this message needs to be multiline.

To be more specific, I'm trying to change this:
This is my message to send the invite

Into this:
This is my message
to send the invite

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using FBWebDialog. In particular I'm using this function:

```
+ (void)presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:(FBSession *)session
                                    message:(NSString *)message
                                      title:(NSString *)title
                                 parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                    handler:(FBWebDialogHandler)handler {
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:session
                                              message:message
                                                title:title
                                           parameters:parameters
                                              handler:handler
                                          friendCache:nil];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please take some time to format your question

Comment: You got it @Madbreaks